# Javascript - Managing a new window opened by a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Usually in javascript when you need to manage a new window it is used the `open()` method and in case you need to manage the parent it is used the `opener` property, like in this example:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");    // Opens a new window
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");                // Text in the new window
myWindow.opener.document.write("<p>This is the source window!</p>"); // Text in the window that created the new window
```

My problem is when the new window has been opened by a form, as in this example in jQuery:

```
$('#form1').html('<form id="f1" action="welcome.php" method="post" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" name="name" value="a"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="a@b.com"><input type="submit"></form>');
$("#f1").submit();
```

How to manage the new window(using by the `target="_blank"`), associating it to a new object in javascript?
I need to apply the `opener` property to the new window opened by the form...

Comment: [this answer](http://okwave.jp/qa/q6731947.html) shows referring window object by name, "function getWindow".If you can set name instead of '_blank', you can access the window.

Answer (score 0):

How about set window object to operner window's property in new window's javascript?

In the new window(in your code "welcome.php"):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.opener.newWindowObj = window;
});
```

In the opener window:

```
// check window object exists
alert(window.newWindowObj);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not the owner of welcome.php in the server (welcome.php it is just an example, in the real code it is another php file)